# Highlight non-matching data

Tags: excel, vba, highlight, conditional-formatting

How do I apply conditional formatting rules using VBA?

I have the following dataset:
[image]

The first column is the UNIQUE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER which is usually in two records, followed by other columns showing data related to the account numbers.

I want to apply a conditional formatting rule that if  UNIQUE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER is matching, but any other column isn't (for the two matching records) then highlight it yellow.

For example:
[image]

The account number MTMB^1^10000397 was matching twice but the Arrears_flag wasn't matching so I want to highlight it yellow.

In this example I can only apply the match & Mismatch for one column.

```vb
Dim rg1 As Range
Set rg1 = Range("E3", Range("E3").End(xlDown))
Dim uv As UniqueValues
Set uv = rg1.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues

uv.DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
uv.Interior.Color = vbRed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the answer

```
Sub actin()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row


mrow = 0
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, "E"), Sheet1.Cells(i - 1, "E")), Sheet1.Cells(i, "E")) > 0 Then
mrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Cells(i, "E"), Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, "E"), Sheet1.Cells(i - 1, "E")), 0)
End If


If mrow = 0 Then GoTo eee

If Sheet1.Cells(i, "G") <> Sheet1.Cells(mrow, "G") Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, "G").Interior.Color = vbYellow
Sheet1.Cells(mrow, "G").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

If Sheet1.Cells(i, "H") <> Sheet1.Cells(mrow, "H") Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, "H").Interior.Color = vbYellow
Sheet1.Cells(mrow, "H").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If


eee:
Next i



Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working, adding a new helper column, concatenating the account number and the "ACC_HEADER_POOL" column in column "I", and using `=COUNTIF(I$2:I$5,I2)=1` as the formula on which the conditional formatting is based, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thanks soo much for your input, but it is not convenient for me to create a helper column for each column. My dataset already contains 200 columns and this would make it really hard to work with. But Good methodology!

Comment: @King: You might consider replacing the helper column and `CountIf()` function by `CountIfS()` function, but I'm not that strong using that function.

Comment: That still wouldnt work....As id have to use helper columns for each column.